# How to fit one discrete data set to another with shifting and tilting?

Tags: fitting, discrete

I have two sets of discrete experimental data, each data set consists of many {x,y,z} positions. Both data sets have overlap region; you can merge both data sets together with shifting and tilting one set to another. It's like merging two photos together.

Here, we can write the shifting and the tilting as follows:
    {x,y,z} -> {x+a, y+b, z+ux+vy+c}.

My question is:
How to find the shifting and tilting parameters {a,b,c,u,v} for given two data sets?

My first thought is to minimize the sum of square of residuals between the interpolated surface of one data set and the data points in another data set. It, however, would have multiple local minima, so it might be an initial value problem.

Comment: Look up RANSAC algorithm.

Comment: Are the points tagged?  In other words, do you know necessarily know that point #1 in one data set "matches" point #1 in the other data set?

Comment: @MichaelSeifert No, I do not know which data point in one set matches a point in the other set.

Comment: how would you evaluate how "good" two candidate results are? are you, in the end, going to make a matching between pairs of points?

Comment: @MichaelCurry In the experiment, I will take each data set to have sufficient overlap region. I want to evaluate the goodness whether the area of the overlap region is relevant and the sum of square of residuals is small enough. And I do not make any matching between pairs of points at all.

Comment: @TaikiBessho my instinct would also be minimize sum of squares then. You have a few parameters and a differentiable cost function so could use gradient descent. If you can map each `{x,y,z}` in the first dataset onto an "ideal" target point with which to minimize the squared residual (maybe just `f(x,y,z)`, where `f` is the interpolated surface of the second dataset) you could even use the neural networks framework to fit faster using stochastic gradient descent on a GPU.

Comment: @MichaelCurry Is it do you think too difficult or not realistic to implement this calculation on Mathematica?

Comment: @TaikiBessho I think it would be very feasible. I don't see an easy way to avoid the problem of local extrema, but since you only have 5 parameters you could try NMinimize or FindMinimum. Also check out the neural networks package if you have version 11 or above, it would be easy enough, I think, to frame this as a neural network with one layer that just applies your `{x+a, y+b, z+ux+vy+c}` to its input and minimizes the least squared difference with the target.